# Create a table of percentages based on the values in two columns

Tags: r

I am very lost here, so I apologize if this makes no sense

My original data frame looks like this. 1 indicates yes and 0 indicates no

```
ever_eaten_banana <- c(1,1,0,0)
allergic_banana <- c(1,0,1,0)
ever_eaten_shellfish <- c(0,1,1,1)
allergic_shellfish <- c(0,1,0,0)

df <- data.frame(ever_eaten_banana,allergic_banana,ever_eaten_shellfish,allergic_shellfish)
df

   ever_eaten_banana allergic_banana ever_eaten_shellfish allergic_shellfish
1                 1               1                    0                  0
2                 1               0                    1                  1
3                 0               1                    1                  0
4                 0               0                    1                  0
>
```

My goal is a table that shows the percentage of people who have ever eaten each food who are also allergic to said food, excluding anyone who says they're allergic without ever eating the food.

So for bananas there is only 1 person who has tried bananas who is also allergic to them and 2 people who have tried bananas so I am looking for 50%.

My goal is a table that looks like this

| Food | Percent |
| --- | --- |
| Bananas | 50% |
| Shellfish | 33% |

I fiddled around with trying to make a handful of functions but never got anywhere close so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One option in `tidyverse` - reshape to 'long' format, `replace` the 'allergic' to 0 on all cases that are not having both ever_eaten and allergic as 1 and get the proportions of allergic with ever_eaten grouped by 'Food'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "Food"), 
      names_pattern = "(.*)_([^_]+)$") %>%
   mutate(allergic =+(allergic & ever_eaten)) %>% 
   reframe(Percent = round(100* sum(allergic)/sum(ever_eaten)), .by = 'Food')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  Food      Percent
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 banana         50
2 shellfish      33
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base `table` and `reshape`:

```
dflong <- reshape(
    setNames(df, gsub("ever_eaten", "evereaten", names(df))),
    varying=TRUE, timevar="food", sep="_", direction="long"
)

with(dflong[dflong$evereaten == 1,], prop.table(table(food, allergic),1) )[, 2, drop=FALSE]
#           allergic
#food                1
#  banana    0.5000000
#  shellfish 0.3333333
```